# Appending rows to table inside form element with JavaScript slower than without the form element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, tablesorter

I ended up reporting this issue as a bug. Seems to affect webkit browsers. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=233677

Original question below.

---

I'm using jQuery 1.8.1 with Christian Bach's tablesorter 2 plugin and running into a peculiar problem. (Same problem with jQuery 1.7.1 and tablesorter 1.)

I have a table with hundreds of rows and it sorts in about 1 second.

When I wrap the table in an HTML `<form>` element the tablesorter plugin becomes very slow. A table with ~500 rows takes upwards of 8 seconds to sort.

I'm only calling `$("#table").tablesorter()` with no extra parameters, and just plain HTML with no other JavaScript or CSS.

The HTML for this table is around 1.2mb and each `<td>` contains additional HTML elements such as `<button>`, `<div>`, `<span>`, `<a>`, ...

Any ideas what the `<form>` element may be interfering with? Thanks, /w

Edit: Here's an example with only 10 rows. Scale to 500 for realistic times, and wrap the table in `<form></form>` to see how that slows the sorting. http://pastebin.com/95KAAb88

Comment: Try some other plugins, tablesorter was last updated in 2008 and was written for jQuery 1.2. E.g. https://github.com/padolsey/jQuery-Plugins/blob/master/sortElements/jquery.sortElements.js or http://datatables.net/. Also it is a wise idea to make a working demo of your problem on http://jsfiddle.net/ and not a proken php file on pastebin.

Comment: I was just getting ready to say I've tracked the issue down to the function `appendToTable(table, cache)` on the line `tableBody[0].appendChild(r[pos][j]);`. @dtech, this is a working HTML document and not PHP (You just need to download jQuery and tablesorter and reference them.) I don't have a CDN for tablesorter, so I didn't use jsfiddle.net. I also didn't want to post the full HTML page; it's very ugly and >1mb of text. I've looked at other table sorters, but this is the one the project has chosen and customized (doesn't affect performance). I'm not at liberty to change things.

Comment: @dtech, I tried datatables.net on this table and it worked perfectly. I'm going to recommend that we use this if possible. Thanks for the recommendation. I am still curious as to while `<form>` totally messes up tablesorter, but I'm just going to flag this question as solved.

Comment: I had a similar issue using JQuery Mobile. Table creation was fast until I wrapped it inside a form. My solution was to simply wrap the table in the form after the table was constructed.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered this issue is not unique to tablesorter or datatables. Possibly something with the JavaScript engine in my version of Chrome (23).

I created a simple jsfiddle. Firefox 20.0 doesn't seem to have this issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/wsams/yGpdv/27/

If you open a web developer console and run this script, note the `Appending child` time. This is the time it takes to append a row to the table.

After a couple passes, simply wrap the table in `<form>` like this,

```
<form>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>count</th>
            <th>link</th>
            <th>input</th>
            <th>button</th>
            <th>count</th>
            <th>link</th>
            <th>input</th>
            <th>button</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="tr1">
            <td>item 1</td><td><a href="text.html?key=value&amp;dog=poodle&amp;cat=siamese">a big link</a></td><td><input type="text" value="something" /></td><td><button type="submit" name="test" value="why">why this</button></td><td>item 1</td><td><a href="text.html?key=value&amp;dog=poodle&amp;cat=siamese">a big link</a></td><td><input type="text" value="something" /></td><td><button type="submit" name="test" value="why">why this</button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

Now run the script again and note the `Appending child` times. I'm seeing it going from about 0.040ms per append to ~8ms. It also seems somewhat exponential as you add more rows.

To me it has to be an issue with the native JavaScript DOM functions, but I'm not an expert in this area.

Comment: I do have an updated fork of tablesorter on github: http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/ The problem with the original plugin is that it would append each row, one at a time, into the DOM which is a much slower method than just doing it all at once. I didn't add this as an answer because I'm not sure why wrapping it in a form would make that much of a difference. Datatables is a good alternative, but I didn't like it because it's 200k+ in size which is why I started updating tablesorter.

Comment: Hi @Mottie. I gave your version a try and it was a bit faster, but still had similar issues with the really large tables I'm dealing with. I was hoping I could swap it out for yours since we have a lot of customization and Java logic to build the table. I believe I'm running into worse issues with datatables. This table just needs to be re-designed; it shouldn't be megabytes of plain text. Thanks for the suggestion.